# Rails: How do I check my model objects for validation errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get my app to display any validation errors ActiveRecord may be elicting. My problem is I don't know how to check my object for errors without it crashing. I am doing `@user.errors.any?` , but this does not work because if there are not any errors, it is going to call errors on `@user` and be null and cause an error. How can I check my `@user` object for errors without Rails crashing?

```
  def update
    @user = current_user.update(user_params)
    if @user.errors.empty?
      flash[:notice] = "Update Successful"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Update Failed"
    end
    redirect_to "/"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`@user.errors` should return `ActiveModel::Errors` even when it has no errors.
If you want to call method on something that could be an object or nil, you can use `try` method.
http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `@user`, as you already have `current_user` (plus, you're redirecting anyway, so the assignment will not be used). Also, you use a method that [returns false when invalid](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update), so you don't need the extra check.

```
  def update
    flash[:notice] = if current_user.update(user_params)
      'Update Successful'
    else
      'Update Failed'
    end
    redirect_to '/' # Try redirect_to root_path
  end
```

If, for some reason, `current_user` is nil, put the controller (or at least the action) behind authentication, or use something like this (or even better, [the null object pattern](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rails-refactoring-example-introduce-null-object)):

```
  def update
    flash[:notice] = if current_user && current_user.update(user_params)
      'Update Successful'
    else
      'Update Failed'
    end
    redirect_to '/' # Try redirect_to root_path
  end
```